# Double-Mouse-1 selects text and symbol in Emacs

Tags: emacs

When I double click `abcd_efg`, emacs selects the part `abcd` or `efg` depending on what I click. How can I select the whole string `abcd_efg` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Either do what [@jcubic](https://superuser.com/a/556813/167207) suggested *or* just ***double-click the `_` char*** in the symbol name.  That's what I do.

That way, you can do either: select a word (e.g., a piece of a symbol name) or select an entire symbol name.  Yes, you have to pay a little more attention to where you click, but you get more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")` that will define underscore as part of the word.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, which I slightly modified from a google post (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/9UDFLLjBeKU)

```lisp
(defun get-word-boundary ()
 "Return the boundary of the current word.
 The return value is of the form: (cons pos1 pos2).
 "
 (save-excursion
  (let (p1 p2)
   (progn
    (skip-chars-backward "-A-Za-z0-9_.") ;; here you can choose which symbols to use
    (setq p1 (point))
    (skip-chars-forward "-A-Za-z0-9_.") ;; put the same here
    (setq p2 (point)))
   (cons p1 p2)
  ))
)
(defun select-word ()
"Mark the url under cursor."
(interactive)
;  (require 'thingatpt)
(let (bds)
  (setq bds (get-word-boundary))

  (set-mark (car bds))
  (goto-char (cdr bds))
  )
)
(global-set-key [double-mouse-1] 'select-word)
```